# How to prevent oracle database from UPDATEing entries when using Data Load Definitions in APEX?

Tags: csv, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am using Oracle Application Express Data Load Definitions to give the end user application the capability to import new data into the database via .csv files.

All the entries defined in the .csv files are always new and unknown to the database and have to be inserted. But sometimes the database does not perform an INSERT, but rather an UPDATE. This results in falsely altering existing entries.

Can I somehow prevent oracle from UPDATEing and force him to INSERT.

Edit: It appears that this especially happens with composite primary keys.

Comment: Updates will be generated if the the data being loaded has the same primary key values as an existing entry in the table. So your issue would appear to be with how the primary key has been defined for the target table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The primary key is set by a sequence called by a trigger. So the .csv file does not include the primary key.

Comment: Just the composite primary keys are defined in the .csv file. But they are also always new and unique to the database.

Comment: When you create a Data Load definition, APEX requires you to specify the Unique Column(s) (not necessarily the table's Primary Key). Whatever you have specified, APEX will use this to match data from your CSV to the data in the table; if a match is found, it will try to update the row. If you want inserts only, you need to make sure no matches are found.

Comment: I usually use the Data Load functionality with a "staging table" that is always empty for the user's session (I use the APEX session ID as part of the primary key) by deleting any existing data before the Data Load starts processing. On the 2nd-to-last page, I add a PL/SQL process to copy the data from the staging table to the target table. That way there are no collisions.